# Can I add Units (C, F, K) to a Flutter App the same way localizations and themes work?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter is very helpful in giving me ways to use AppLocalizations and Themes. But the same way that I want the app to change when I flick on dark mode, and the same way it does that with my Language Strings, I want the App to be able to switch different Units of Measurements.

My question is - what is the EASIEST way of achieving this. I am sure I could whip up a listener into every String that waits for a change and then updates the value but I am sure there must be a better way, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [ValueNotifier](https://medium.com/@thekavak/flutter-valuenotifier-with-examples-66b3933d7036) with custom enum.
Somethink like this:

```
enum Unit{
   C,
   K,
   F,
}

final listenable = ValueNotifier<Unit>(Unit.K);

...widgets
ValueListenableBuilder<Unit>(
  valueListenable: listenable,
  builder: (_, unit, __) => Text(unit.name);
),
...widgets
```